# Specific Japanese character not displaying properly in PDF

Tags: php, pdf, unicode, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm trying to print Asian characters in PDF.
Although I was successful in rendering the Asian characters in PDF I'm facing a small issue in one of the characters that is displaying.

I have used fireflysung.ttf for displaying the characters and the asian word is スズキグループ 行動指針 – ステップ 1.

But for ー in PDF, its showing square brackets.
What should I need to do to make this character to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys its working for me now.I have used HanaMinA font to support JAPANESE characters. Actually the Hanazono fonts (HanaMinA, HanaMinB) have full support for all 3 extensions and include 96k+ glyphs. Actually it will display all Asian characters including Korean, Chinese and Japanese.