# UTF-8 not working when trying to export html table to PDF using tablexport

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8, jspdf, export-to-pdf

This is the existing fiddle that shows exporting table to pdf using tableexport.js.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelk/6gd9w79u/)

In the above fiddle, UTF-8 works for excel but not PDF. Please try replacing english text with Japanese and observe that Japanese text is not properly exported to PDF.

```
 <th data-field="name">こんにちは</th>
```

Is there anything missing with this plugin?

Comment: so, utf-8 is working for you when exporting the pdf?I can see japanese text in excel but not in pdf. i think the problem is with pdf not excel

Comment: maybe this one can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/40234715/5870896

Comment: I am looking for a solution using tableexport.js

Comment: can someone help me?

Comment: Full unicode support is not available in jspdf which tableexport.js is using: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

table export library support utf-8  I found a solution edit the file /tableExport/tableExport.js line 280 with bellow code

```
    var base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) } // New base64

// var base64data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(excelFile); OLD LINE

var base64data = "base64," + base64(excelFile); // New line with new base64
```